# setInterval not call function with arguments

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

I was trying to repeatedly call a function using setInterval. When I call a function without arguments, it works. However, on calling a function with arguments, the function is called only once.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/L0eyzveq/6/#&togetherjs=neh0tPqKKR) is the js fiddle

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="./check.js">

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

check.js Without arguments - works

```
setInterval(myfun,100)
var mycounter = 0;

function myfun()
{
    console.log(mycounter++)
}
```

check.js With arguments - does not work

```
setInterval(myfun(0),1000)

function myfun(mycounter)
{
    console.log(mycounter++)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When you add the parentheses the function is called right away, and the returned result is used in the interval, which in your case is the default return value of `undefined`.

What you're really doing is

```
var result = myfun(0); // returns undefined

setInterval(result, 1000); // no go, result is undefined

function myfun(mycounter) {

}
```

if you want to pass arguments, the easiest is to just use an anonymous function

```
setInterval(function() {
    myfun(0);
}, 1000);
```

Modern browser (not IE9 and below) now support passing arguments directly in `setInterval`

```
setInterval(myfun, 1000, 0); // "0" is passed as the first argument to myfun()
```

of course, incrementing the variable can only be done if the variable exists in a scope outside the callback function  for the interval

Comment: this is my code now. It just prints zeros though.
setInterval(function(){
    myfun(0)
},1000)

function myfun(mycounter)
{
    console.log(mycounter++)
}
How can I increment mycounter inside myfun, and still get an increasing count displayed.

Comment: @PepperBoy - The function in the interval is called anew every time, and every time it gets passed `0`, so you can't increment this way, the variable has no kept state, it's a new variable every time. If you want to iincrement the variable has to be stored somewhere outside the `myfun` function, and generally the way to do that is what you're already doing in your first example.

Answer (score 1):

right...

what setInterval wants is a function that it can call,

in the first case you are providing the function

in the second case you are calling the function and then returning its value

to accomplish what you are trying to do in the second case you would do this:

```
setInterval(function() {myFun(20)}, 1000}
```

which creates a NEW function that wraps your call to myFun inside it... comprehend?

Now the other thing to keep in mind is that setInterval *keeps* calling the function forever until you stop it.... so you could do this:

```
var counter = 20;
setInterval(function() {counter = counter-1; if (counter > 0) myFun()}, 1000)
```

which will call myFun every second until counter expires...

But this is still not perfect a the interval will keep running forever so what you want is something like this (its a working example, click the run button at the bottom)

```js
    function nTimes(fn, count, time) {
      var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (count > 0) {
          count = count - 1;
          fn(count);
        } else {
          clearInterval(interval);
        }
      }, time)
    };


    function myFun(x) {
      $('#output').html($('#output').html() + x + '</br>')
    }
    nTimes(myFun, 20, 1000)
```

```html
<div id='output'></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Mitch VanDuyn,  thanks I understand the reason. However, this is the code I have now. It always outputs 0. setInterval(function() {myfun(0)}, 1000)

function myfun(mycounter)
{
    console.log(mycounter++)
}
As I said, I want myfun to have an argument, and display increasing count.

Comment: Sure just pass the count to fn in the above example

Answer (score 0):

Working **Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/0tesf2rk/

```
var counter = {

  value: 0,

  increase: function () {

    console.log(counter.value);

    counter.value++;

  }

};

counter.value = 20;

setInterval(counter.increase, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks. But as I said, I want to be able to pass the initial value, say 20, as an argument to the function which is called by setInterval, and subsequent increments would happen inside the helper function, say myfun.