# reactjs have function run repeatedly

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to have "asdf" written to console every second in reactjs. I am using setInterval.

here is my code:

```
<head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react-dom.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/babel">

class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(console.log("asdf"),1000)
  }

  render() { return (<div/ >) }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <NameForm />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

</script>
</body>
```

Currently, asdf is only written to console once. Why is this? Thanks

Comment: This link explains what and why your code fails: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34625574/setinterval-not-call-function-with-arguments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently you are passing `undefined` to `setInterval` because `console.log()`return `undefined`. Wrap it in a 'function' and pass as parameter

```
componentDidMount() {this.interval = setInterval(() => console.log("qwer"),1000)}
```

Answer (score 2):

setInterval need a pointer for a function ,but you gave function to first argument.

```
setInterval(function (){

//your function 

}, 3000)
```

or in es6 way , you can use arrow functions

```
setInterval(() => {
 //your function comes here
}, 3000)
```